# Elasticsearch - Dynamic date into filter range

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to filter a request by asking him to retrieve only the dates LOWER than today. I don't want to retrieve data that contains dates GREATER than today.

Actually, I have some data with date before today, and after today, but *I can not dynamize the value of today's date*. **My date format is MM/dd/yyyy**

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": ...,
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "data.content.publication.keyword": {
              "lt": "04/01/2018" // Dynamic
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    // aggs
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) in order to express today's date dynamically, it goes like this:

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": ...,
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "data.content.publication.keyword": {
              "lt": "now/d"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    // aggs
}
```